# Keeping checkbox state after submit with status checked on first page load

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I have this html form with checkboxes that keep their status checked or unchecked after submitting the form and reloading the page:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="keyword1" value="keyword1" <?php if(isset($_POST['keyword1'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />keyword1
<input type="checkbox" name="keyword2" value="keyword2" <?php if(isset($_POST['keyword2'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />keyword2
<input type="checkbox" name="keyword2" value="keyword3" <?php if(isset($_POST['keyword2'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />keyword3
<input type="submit"  />
</form>
```

Problem is, that at first page load the checkboxes are unchecked. Is there any possibility to have all checkboxes with status checked at the beginning and then keep their new status after submit? So far I could not figure out how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: If you add a name and value to your input button you could check and see if it's been submitted already.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, for example with cookies or javascript.

Comment: So no easier way with html/php techniques?

Answer (score 1):

you could use $_SESSION instead of $_POST :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="keyword1" value="keyword1" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['keyword1'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />keyword1
```

And then put this on the top of your file :

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['my_form'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['keyword1'])) {
        $_SESSION['keyword1'] = 'checked';
    }
}
```

Comment: To use sessions is the right idea. Just don't get it to work properly. checkbox always stays checked. Thing I need to use some if..else.. clause in the input field to get it work..?